# can not convert parameter 1 from int into &int

Tags: c++

Lets imagine I have got functions:

```
int switcherINT(char &c){
    switch (c){
    case '1': return 1; break;
    case '2': return 2; break;  
    case '3': return 3; break;
    case '4': return 4; break;
    case '5': return 5; break;
    case '6': return 6; break;
    case '7': return 7; break;
    case '8': return 8; break;
    case '9': return 9; break;
    case '0': return 0; break;
    default: return err;
    }
}
char switcherCHAR(int &c){
    switch (c){
    case 1: return '1'; break;
    case 2: return '2'; break;  
    case 3: return '3'; break;
    case 4: return '4'; break;
    case 5: return '5'; break;
    case 6: return '6'; break;
    case 7: return '7'; break;
    case 8: return '8'; break;
    case 9: return '9'; break;
    case 0: return '0'; break;
    default: return errCH;
    }
}
```

and I am trying to compute nest expression:

```
c.str[i] = switcherCHAR(switcherINT(pthis->str[pthis->size-i-1])-switcherINT(pb->str[pb->size-i-1])-loc);
```

where

```
longMath *pthis(this),*pb(&b);
longMath c;
class longMath{
protected:
    char* str;
    int size;

protected:
........
```

compiler says:
"can not convert parameter 1 from int into &int"
Haw can I solve this problem?

Comment: By not passing by reference, or by passing a `const` reference. You cannot bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: you mean this char switcherCHAR(const int &c) ?
Mistake still accure

Comment: That should work, even though I would use `switcherCHAR(int i)`.

Answer (score 4):

The expression that you've given as an argument to `switcherCHAR` gives you a temporary `int`. You cannot pass a temporary as a reference - unless you make the reference `const`. Just change `switcherCHAR` to take a `const int&` (and while you're at it, make `switcherINT` take a `const char&`). However, this are very simple types and you're probably better off just taking them by value. So change them to take just `int` and `char`.

Nonetheless, your functions are pretty strange. It is very easy to convert between a number `x` and it's `char` counterpart just by doing `'0' + x`. The numerical digit characters are guaranteed to be in consecutive order. So if you take the value of `'0'` and add, lets say, `5`, you will get the value of the character `'5'`.

Comment: I have changed int switcherINT(const char &c);
bool switcher(const char &c);
But mistake still exist -  "can not convert parameter 1 from int into &int" ...\

Comment: @AntonKizema You've changed them both to take `const char&`? Then how are you getting an error about `int&`?

Comment: or just `int` which might be faster

Comment: Yes they both are const char& and const int&

Comment: sorry, my mistake, haven't notised smth.
Last question - why should we put const there everywere, if it is not hard to explain..

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better to use functions like this:

```
int switcherINT(const char &c) {
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? c - '0' : err;
}

char switcherCHAR(const int &c) {
    return (c >= 0 && c <= 9) ? '0' + c : errCH;
}
```